# Showing a div depending on which link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

This is very common practice, where you click on a link to reveal some other div, and depending on link clicked the div will change .. but what I have won't work. Is there a better way to do this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wn2FE/2/

Here is my code:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Info Div #1</a> 
    <a href="#">Info Div #2</a> 
    <a href="#">Info Div #3</a> 
    <a href="#">Info Div #4</a> 
</nav>

<div id="one">Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div id="two">Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div id="three">Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div id="four">Lorem ipsum...</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
$("nav a").click(function() {
    switch($(this)) {
        case $(this).index() === 0:
            $("div#one").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");

        case $(this).index() === 1:
            $("div#two").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");

        case $(this).index() === 2:
            $("div#three").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");

        case $(this).index() === 3:
            $("div#four").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
    }
});
});
```

I see no errors in the console .. but my divs will not show up. Also this doesn't seem like a very smart way to do this, maybe someone can suggest something cleaner?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a lot easier without the switch/case and using ID's.
I'd reccomend using the same class for the DIV's, but for the example I just used `$('div')` as those are the only DIV's

```
$(function () {
    $("nav a").click(function () {
        $('div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wn2FE/4/)

Comment: Wow .. now I feel stupid :/ thank you!! If you don't mind answering, how would I remove the div if I click the same link again?

Comment: @Deviant - replace the last `show()` in the code above with `toggle()`

Answer (score 2):

Your switch is wrong, you don't have break's too. It should be like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("nav a").click(function () {
        switch ($(this).index()) {
            case 0:
                $("div#one").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
                break;

            case 1:
                $("div#two").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
                break;

            case 2:
                $("div#three").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
                break;
            case 3:
                $("div#four").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });


});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wn2FE/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the switch statement is incorrect:

```
$("nav a").click(function() {
    switch($(this).index()) {
        case 0:
            $("div#one").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
            break;
        case 1:
            $("div#two").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
            break;
        case 2:
            $("div#three").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
            break;
        case 3:
            $("div#four").addClass("display").siblings().removeClass("display");
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .toggle() to show and hide the divs.

```
var $one = $("#one");

$("#link1").on("click", function(){
    $one.toggle();
});
```

Here's an update to your fiddle - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn2FE/3/)

Answer (score 0):

What is normally done is add a class "hide" to the divs you want to hide, then whenever you click a link, you remove the class to that div. It is pretty simple and straightforward to do this with jQuery, here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn2FE/5/)

Here's the HTML

```
    <nav>
    <a href="#" data-value="one">Info Div #1</a>    
    <a href="#" data-value="two">Info Div #2</a>    
    <a href="#" data-value="three">Info Div #3</a>  
    <a href="#" data-value="four">Info Div #4</a>   
</nav>

<div id="one" class="hide">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
<div id="two" class="hide">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
<div id="three" class="hide">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
<div id="four" class="hide">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function(){
$("nav a").click(function() {
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data-value')).removeClass('hide')
});
});
```

CSS:

```
    nav {
    border: 1em double lightgray;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
} 

.hide {
    display: none;
}
div.display {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Just to mention `<a>` don't have a `value` attribute. You can say `data-value` but just `value` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data` custom attribute to "tell" jQuery which div to trigger. Consider the following:

HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" data-id="one">Info Div #1</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="two">Info Div #2</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="three">Info Div #3</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="four">Info Div #4</a> 
</nav>

<div id="one" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... One</div>
<div id="two" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Two</div>
<div id="three" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Three</div>
<div id="four" class="toggle_content">Lorem ipsum... Four</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var div_id = $(this).data('id');

    $('.toggle_content').hide();
    $('#' + div_id).toggle();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/44hvd/

Notice, I added `data-id` to all the navigation links. Values are equal to respective divs' IDs. In addition, I hide all the others divs using `toggle_content` class, instead of using `$('div')` as a selector, which would be rather reckless.